# How to get power bi dashboard in our own application?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am new to power bi. I have power bi account there I created some dashboards with some reports, now I want to consume those dashboard and report using power bi rest API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/)in our own application. Our application we used the .net core for back-end and angular 6 for the front end. We need to call power bi API from the .net core. If I change report in power it should also reflect in our application. I am new so I am not understanding from where to start?

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading these:

- [Embedding with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding)
- [Tutorial: Embed a Power BI report, dashboard, or tile into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers)
- [Microsoft Power BI Embedded Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)

In essence, you need to authenticate using [Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries (ADAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries), obtain the [embedUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/getdashboardingroup#example) of the dashboard, it's id and the id of the group in which it is. It will be loaded in a div section of a html file using the [embedded client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). For more details look at the official [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples). `App Owns Data` means that for authenticating you are using one account, which your application knows (e.g. user name and password stored in the configuration), while `User Owns Data` means that each user uses his own Power BI credentials to access the embedded elements.